# Linq-to-Sql execute custom stored procedure for update records

Tags: linq-to-sql

I little confused about updating data with a stored procedure in linq 2 sql.
My question is: when I use stored procedure to update some data in data base (but this stored 
procedure doesn't mapped to some particular entity) is I shoul invoke SubmitChanges after it. And also what about transaction when I invoke a number of such procedures in loop, should I explicit create transaction through Connection.BeginTransaction() method or model do it for me?

Again, I know how it works when stored procedure linked with some entity in model, but now I wont to use custom stored procedure that update records in a number of tables.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Linq-to-SQL doesn't interface very well with stored procedures - if you're serious about using sprocs, I would recommend "upgrading" to Entity Framework in .NET 4 - **much** better support for stored procs there!

Comment: @marc_s, in what way(s) does Linq-to-SQL not interface well with stored procedures?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: two main things: first of all, you cannot return a result set from a stored procedure that doesn't correspond exactly to an entity in your model (EF does support this by the ability to define specific "complex types" for this), and secondly, you can only execute stored procs in L2S, while in EF4, you can assign stored procedures for each entity type, for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE operations (and you can e.g. assign one stored proc for DELETE and leave EF4 to handle the other operations by generating SQL code staements)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I appreciate your reply.   Regarding your two points:  1) Linq-To-Sql requires that the results for a stored procedure be mapped to an entity, but there's no reason that you can't create custom types (entiteis) for your SP and annotate it with `[Table]`, `[Column]`, and `[Association]` attributes as usual.  I do this all the time for SPs that return custom types.  2) In fact, Linq-To-Sql does support custom SPs for insert/update/delete:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546186.aspx

Comment: @Kirk Woll: yes, sure, it works - if you know and understand how. But you don't have any tool support for this. EF4 offers a "Create Complex Type" for any stored procedure and will do all this mapping magic for you, if need be.

Comment: Makes sense @marc_s, thanks for pointing out the tooling gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating non-entity data via stored procedure and LINQ to SQL is very straightforward.  Just drag the stored procedure from Server Explorer onto *empty space* in the DBML designer (so it won't try to return entity objects) and call the associated generated method in your code like this:

```
myDataContext.MyStoredProcedureMethod();
```

The action is performed immediately, so you don't need to call SubmitChanges().

To wrap this call (or loop, or whatever) in a LINQ to SQL transaction, see the [instructions and examples here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/826145.aspx) for how to use LINQ to SQL transactions.